# How to get value of Java Map in Typescript

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot as backend and Angular 7 as frontend in an application. I have to send map as response. For instance, say:

```
  Map<String, Object> additionalResponse = new HashMap<>() {
        {
            put("key1","value2");
            put("key2","value2");
           
        }
    };
```

I pass this map via response DTO to angular which is:

```
public class SearchResponseDto implements Serializable {
private Map<String, Object> additionalResponse;
}
```

Now on angular, I am using it as:

```
 export class SearchResponseDto {
     additionalResponse: Map<string, any>;
   }
```

I can get value from **additionalResponse** but when I try to use get function in additionalResponse, it is giving me **undefined** value. What should I do to use **additionalResponse** as Map on angular?

Edit:
I am using the backend response in Angular as:

```
      fetchData() {
        fetchResponse().
           .subscribe(
              response => {
     
                this.response = response;
          
            },
           errorResponse => {
       
          },
       );
      }



 fetchResponse(): Observable<SearchResponseDto> {
            return this.http.post<SearchResponseDto>(
              <api-endpoints>
            );
          }
```

And, trying to use as **this.response.additionalResponse.get('key1')** and I am getting value as **undefined** but I am getting value from **this.response.additionalResponse**

On Postman, I am getting response as:

```
{
  "additionalResponse": {
    "key1": "value2",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
}
```

Comment: How is the data serialized? Have you checked the responses through `curl`/Insomnia/Postman? If the data is serialized as JSON, it should "simply work".

Comment: Yes, I am getting response as:                                                                                                   
  {"additionalResponse": {
    "key1": "value2",
    "key2": "value2"
 } }
But when I try to use it using like map.get('key1') , I am getting undefined value.

Comment: Your response has JSON type, not Map

Comment: Can you please include the code where you receive the response from the backend in the frontend?

Comment: @Turing85 Included the implementation part. Could you please look into it?

Comment: I am not TypeScript-expert, so my knowledge on the subject is limited. I just asked for the information necessary to answer the question in hopes that readers would be more likely to answer your question.

Comment: Where do you call this line  -> this.response.additionalResponse.get('key1') ?

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu right after it is set and also in the component html

Comment: What does console.log(this.response) show?

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu it shows the correct response. Also, this.response.additionalResponse giving the correct response, but when I use get() it is giving me the issue

Comment: @SerhiiBilyk could you please tell the correct implementation, as I am new to typescript and frontend as a whole

Comment: Replace Map<string, any> with [key: string]: any in your class declaration then instead of this.response.additionalResponse.get('key1')  use this.response.additionalResponse['key1']

Comment: [key: string]: any ? It says  Cannot find name key. But I got the solution, I replaced Map<string, any> with just any and can get value from this.response.additionalResponse.key1, don't know if it's a good  practise.

Comment: [key: string]: any is functionally equivalent of Map<string, any>, it should work if you wrap it with curly braces like this:  additionalResponse: { [key: string]: any };

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu thank you very much, it's working now. +1 to you, just a curiosity, why Map<string, any> is not working? Sorry for my ignorance as I am basically very new to frontend technology. I just started working in the front end around 1 month ago, in my  4.5+ years of a professional career.

Comment: JSON coming from your BE can not be converted to a Map, it is just a regular Object in JS, with the syntax I mentioned above you can specify the Types of the keys and values of that object. Map is not equal to Object. If you create a Map with some values, then console log it you can tell the difference between the Map and the response coming from your BE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, I replaced **Map<string, any>** with just **any** and can get value from **this.response.additionalResponse.key1**, don't know if it's a good practice though. As said in the above comment, it might be due to JSON type but I really not finding a way to declare it accordingly.

Comment: Edit:  I can use this as well additionalResponse: { [key: string]: any };

Comment: Using `any` is the very bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const response= {
  "additionalResponse": {
    "key1": "value2",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
}

const { additionalResponse } = response;

const map = Object.entries(additionalResponse).map(([key, value])=>{
  console.log(key, value)
})
```

OR you can convert it to the Map:

```js
const map = new Map();
const response= {
  "additionalResponse": {
    "key1": "value2",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
}

const { additionalResponse } = response;

Object.entries(additionalResponse).forEach(([key, value])=>{
  console.log(key, value)
  map.set(key, value)
})
```

[UPDATED]

```js
     fetchData() {
        fetchResponse().
           .subscribe(
              response => {
     
                const { additionalResponse } = response;

               Object.entries(additionalResponse).forEach(([key, value])=>{
               console.log(key, value)
               map.set(key, value)
               })
          
            },
           errorResponse => {
       
          },
       );
      }
```

Comment: response is coming from the backend, I cannot define it in typescript.

Comment: I have defined response variable as example ) You should use the one from callback. Please see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Iterate throught the response.additionalResponse object response and create new map and extract the key like below:

```
var mapResp = new Map();
for(key in response.additionalResponse){
    mapResp.set(key, response.additionalResponse[key]);
}
mapResp.get('key1'); // this will give you value2
```